# Scrolling on my table view break my view items and some backgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, tableview, tabbar

I have some issue about table view scrolling ı have no issue everything work perfectly [without scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgTYl.jpg) but when ı try to scroll tableview ı get this image[with scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lq8K.jpg)
my top view is dismiss and tab bar items background is change.I cant find any solution about this topic.Thx for everything

Comment: Can you please share the code for the better sake of understanding of a problem ?

Comment: can you want spesific method or all code for main page @ShabnamSiddiqui ı think we can look spesific method

Comment: How did you organised tab bar, table view, and others view ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solve the problem.Because of my label under the navigation bar , when ı try scroll to above of page my label will disappear also ı change my navigation bar background color to my main view background color :) so the other problem was solved